# Hyperlinks in Line Chart

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport, jasperserver

I've added hyperlinks and tooltips to a line chart in iReport/JasperReports Server Professional 4.7. They work but I seem to have complications. How can I associate the hyperlink and tooltip with the actual plotted points on the line? I had to sweep my mouse very slowly and carefully across the screen to even find them. The tooltip and hyperlink for the fourth point (blue arrow) on my line shows up when I mouse over where I have put a green dot.

[image]